# Using scrapy crawler to extract Json Data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape product data that happens to be in an XHR request. I am able to scrape the desired data if I absolutely reference the XHR url. But the site I am trying to scrape has a different XHR request for each product page crawled.

Here is a product https://www.midwayusa.com/product/939287480?pid=598174
Now I did notice that if you take the url of each page and put [data] https://www.midwayusa.com/productdata/939287480?pid=598174 you can get the XHR request that way. I don't know how to do that with a crawler being my second scraper and new to python.

So basically what would we be the easiest way to get the JSON data from each page crawled?

```
class PwspiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = 'pwspider'
allowed_domains = ['midwayusa.com']
start_urls = ['https://www.midwayusa.com/s?searchTerm=backpack']

# restricting css
le_backpack_title = LinkExtractor(restrict_css='li.product')

# Callback to ParseItem backpack and follow the parsed URL Links from URL
rule_Backpack_follow = Rule(le_backpack_title, callback='parse_item', follow=False)

# Rules set so Bot can't leave URL
rules = (
    rule_Backpack_follow,
)

def start_requests(self):
    yield scrapy.Request('https://www.midwayusa.com/s?searchTerm=backpack',
        meta={'playwright': True})


def parse_item(self, response):
    data = json.loads(response.body)
    yield from data['products']
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1Oow.png)

Comment: I don't understand what you want to put in XHR url - it looks the same.

Comment: put code with correct indentations. Wrong indentations can change everything.

Comment: One shows the Item, and the other shows the JSON for the page. I want to crawl the  JSON for each product page.

Comment: if both use the same url but second send it as XHR then you may need to write normal  function to send `Requests` with header `'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'`

Comment: I hate to say it but I've been looking up request and x-request all morning and now I'm even more confused. I know how to get JSON data when directly calling the json API link. I can't figure out how to get that link when using a crawl spider.

Comment: maybe remove LinkExtractor and create own function

Comment: i tested page and it uses JavaScript to generate page `?searchTerm=backpack` but it doesn't get data from other url - it has all information directly in HTML as `<script> window.icvData = {...} </script>`. And the same with page `?pid=598174` - it has all data as `<script> window.icvData = {...} </script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested page and it uses JavaScript to generate page with search results but it doesn't get data from other url - it has all information directly in HTML as

```
<script> 
    window.icvData = {...} 
</script>
```

And the same is with product pages. They also have data directly in HTML.

Sometimes they may have extra line with `window.icvData.firstSaleItemId = ...`
but I skip this information.

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy.spiders import Spider

class PwspiderSpider(Spider):

    name = 'pwspider'
    
    allowed_domains = ['midwayusa.com']
    
    start_urls = ['https://www.midwayusa.com/s?searchTerm=backpack']
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        print('url:', response.url)
        
        script = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "window.icvData")]/text()').get()
        #print(script)
        
        text = script.split("window.icvData = ")[-1].split('\n')[0].strip()

        try:
            data = json.loads(text)
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)
            print(text)
            return
        
        #print(data["searchResult"].keys())
        
        products = data["searchResult"]['products']
        
        for item in products:
            #print(item)
            colors = [color['name'] for color in item['swatches']]
            print(item['description'], colors)
            yield response.follow(item['link'], callback=self.parse_product, cb_kwargs={'colors': colors})
        
    def parse_product(self, response, colors):
        print('url:', response.url)
        
        script = response.xpath('//script[contains(text(), "window.icvData")]/text()').get()
        #print(script)
        
        # I uses `.split('\n')[0]` because sometimes it may have second line with `window.icvData.firstSaleItemId = ...` 
        text = script.split("window.icvData = ")[-1].split('\n')[0].strip()
        
        try:
            data = json.loads(text)
            data['colors'] = colors
        except Exception as ex:
            print('Exception:', ex)
            print(text)
            return

        yield data

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
#    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEEDS': {'output.json': {'format': 'json'}},  # new in 2.1
})
c.crawl(PwspiderSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: Thank you for this massively! I'm not sure if I am doing something wrong. But when I run the scraper. It seems like some data is not appearing in my JSON output. For example, this page https://www.midwayusa.com/product/939322596?pid=805285 has a drop-down of three different colors I would only see the details for the olive Drab backpack. Again thank you so much. You really didn't need to go above and beyond!

Comment: I see colors only on page with search results but not on page with details. I add in code `[color['name'] for color in item['swatches']]` to get colors from search results, and I send it from `parse()` to `parse_item() ` using `response.follow(..., cb_kwargs={'colors': colors})` and `def parse_product(self, response, colors):` - so I can add this to json data which it sends to file.